# how to resize thumbnail image

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I am using this function to re-size my thumbnail  ,
 add_image_size( 'portfoliolarg', 120, 120, true);
 the image is corp and resize I just want to resize my Image

Comment: If the images were already uploaded before you added that image size, you will need to either find and download a plugin that will reupload your images or do so manually.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: `add_image_size()` is to ADD a new image size into your WordPress installation.

Now, as you said:

> *I just want to resize my Image*

You need to enter into your wp-admin panel. Then Settings » Media, and change the thumbnail size there.
[image: WordPress Media Settings]

Just change the thumbnail size there. Now use the plugin: [**Regenerate Thumbnails**](http://www.viper007bond.com/wordpress-plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) by *Viper007Bond* to make your new image sizes.

So, after then, if you use:

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );
```

it will echo the new thumbnail image (120 x 120).

> **WARNING:** Changing image sizes and regenerating new image sizes, doesn't delete previously created sizes, just add new sized images into the server space. So the process is somewhat space-killing theory, if not smartly handled.